# How to get the name of day in Arabic in sql server

Tags: sql-server, date, arabic

I want to get the name of the day in arabic like 'جمعة' in sql server 2008.
I tried this code :

```
SET LANGUAGE German
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) AS 'german'

SET LANGUAGE us_english
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) AS 'english'

SET LANGUAGE Arabic
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) AS 'arabic'
```

But it respectively produced :

Freitag

Friday

Friday

The arabic language does not produced 'جمعة' as it was expected. It produced 'Friday' instead.

Answer (score 3):

It may not be supported (yet) by Microsoft. If you run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages where name = 'Arabic'
```

then you will see what Month and Day names it supports for Arabic.

The `months` seem OK, but on my system (SQL 2008) for `days` it returns:

```
days
--------------------------------------------------------
Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday
```

This will probably be the same for you.

And because `sys.syslanguages` is a System table, you can not modify it yourself. I do not know if this has been solved in newer SQL Server versions. Until then you will have to use another mechanism to achieve what you want.